# Best way to run different versions of a project on GIT?

Tags: git, architecture

I have to add an additional version of my project for a new customer.

The goals are:

1. One main version of the project that keeps common code and a
   group of customer-oriented versions with specific additions for
   every customer.
2. Be able to upload changes from common version.

The best way would be to break project into independent modules, but I am limited in time and can't stick to that option atm. I am considering 2 options

1. Fork
2. Multiple branches withing the same repo

Are there better way to do it? What are the cons and pros?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a branch naming strategy as follows.

`<customer_name>/<branch_name>`

eg: `customer1/get-products`

The only caveat in this naming strategy is that when you make paths such as `a/b/c` as branch names in git, you cannot later have `a/b` or `a`, so you cannot have a branch named as `customer` and another branch named as `customer/dev`, git wont allow that.

However you can keep branches such as `customer/dev`, `customer/uat`, `customer/master` and have feature branches such as `customer/feature1` etc

Your common functionality can still be in your main branches such as `dev`, `uat`, `master`, etc and you can merge those branches to the individual customer branches when needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have to absolutely keep the code for customers in different repositories for specific reasons, the solution with branches is the easiest (especially to exchange code, cherry-pick, sync,...) and lot less a burden (not having to create a lot of repositories).

And also the easier to start with. You could still create different repositories after if you change your mind.

But, if you don't know, have a look à the 'git worktree' feature to create a worktree for each customer, that could make your life a little easier...